# Angular ng-blur not working with ng-hide

Tags: angularjs

Using a directive `focus-me="inTextModeInput"` in a text input

```
app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
    /*focuses on input
     <input type="text" focus-me="focusInput">
     */
        return {
            scope: { trigger: '=focusMe' },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
                    if(value === true) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            element[0].focus();
                            scope.trigger = false;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Actually having 2 inputs, both uses `focus-me` 
When i programatically set the value to focus on an input the `ng-blur` of other is not called.

NOTE : i am also using this in an ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2):

**Isolated scope**

The blur is called, but you're not seeing that because you've created a directive with an isolated scope. The `ng-blur` is executed on the `$parent` scope. You should only use an isolated scope when the directive is implementing re-useable templates.

**Two way binding on trigger**

The line 'scope.trigger = false' is also setting a different boolean value because it's on a different scope. If you want to assign a value to a variable from a directive you should always wrap the value inside another object: `var focus = { me: true }` and set it like `trigger=focus.me`.

**A better solution**

But I wouldn't set the `trigger` to `false` at all. AngularJS is a MVC/MVVM based framework which has a model state for the user interface. This state should be *idempotent*; meaning that if you store the current state, reload the page and restore the state the user interface should be in the exact same situation as before.

So what you probably need is a directive that

- Has no isolated scope (which allows all other directives to work: ng-blur, ng-focus, ...)
- Keeps track of a boolean, which indicates the focus state
- Sets this boolean to false when the element has lost focus

It's probably easier to see this thing in action: [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Z1mwi?p=preview).

Maybe [this (other) plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eS45IY?p=preview) will give you some more insight on scopes and directives.

**Code**

```
myApp.directive('myFocus', function($parse, $timeout) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function myFocusLink($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrls) {

        var e = $element[0];

        // Grab a parser from the provided expression so we can
        // read and assign a value to it.

        var getModel = $parse($attrs.myFocus);
        var setModel = getModel.assign;

        // Watch the parser -- and focus if true or blur otherwise.

        $scope.$watch(getModel, function(value) {
          if(value) {
            e.focus();
          } else {
            e.blur();
          }
        });

        function onBlur() {
          $timeout(function() {
            setModel($scope, false);  
          });
        }

        function onFocus() {
          $timeout(function() {
            setModel($scope, true);  
          });
        }

        $element.on('focus', onFocus);
        $element.on('blur', onBlur);

        // Cleanup event registration if the scope is destroyed

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          $element.off('focus', onFocus);
          $element.off('blur', onBlur);
        });
    }
  };
});
```